# matlab fir2 frequency response doesn't correspond to magnitude response

Tags: matlab, audio, filter, signal-processing

I am trying to design an FIR with the `fir2` function in Matlab and I'm struggling to get a frequency response of the filter which corresponds to the magnitude function I'm trying to realize.

[image: plots of desired and computed response]

Here's the code I'm using for the filter design, with `x` being the magnitude response as shown in the picture

```
fs = 48000;    %sample rate
fny = fs/2;    %Nyquist frequency
tabs = 512;    %tabs

%frequency resolution 1/3 octave, length=28
f = [0 63 80 100 125 160 200 250 315 400 500 630 800 1000 1250 1600 
2000 2500 3150 4000 5000 6300 8000 10000 12500 16000 20000 fny];

fn = f/(fny);

coeffs = fir2(tabs,fn,x); 

figure(1);
[freq_response,fc] = freqz(coeffs,tabs);
H = abs(freq_response);

subplot(2,1,1);
semilogx(fc*fny,H, 'r');
hold on;
xlim([20 20000]);
title('frequency response of fir2 filter');
xlabel('frequency [Hz]');
ylabel('magnitude [dB]');
grid on;
set(gca,'XTick',[20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000]);

subplot(2,1,2);
semilogx(f,20*log10(x),'b');
title('desired magnitude function');
xlabel('frequency [Hz]');
ylabel('fir coefficients');
grid on;
xlim([20 20000]);
set(gca,'XTick',[20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000]);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we should observe that the function [`freqz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) expects both numerator and denominator polynomial coefficients of the filter's transfer function. You may then also specify additional parameters such as the desired number of points in the frequency response, but this would come *after* the mandatory numerator and denominator polynomial coefficients. For FIR filters which do not have explicit denominator, the implicit denominator is the constant `1`. So the correct way to call `freqz` in your case would be:

```
[freq_response,fc] = freqz(coeffs,1,tabs);
```

Note that by default the returned frequencies are angular frequencies which would cover the `[0,pi]` range. To obtain frequencies in Hz, you need to rescale the angular frequency (as you were trying to do, but were missing a `pi` factor) with `f*fny/pi`. Alternatively you can simply pass the sampling rate to the `freqz` function:

```
[freq_response,fc] = freqz(coeffs,1,tabs,fs);
```

You then have a remaining issue with y-axis scale of the plot. Given that you are trying to plot magnitude responses in dB, you should convert the computed response `H` (which is in linear scale) to dB:

```
[freq_response,fc] = freqz(coeffs,1,tabs,fs);
H = abs(freq_response);
...
semilogx(fc,20*log10(H), 'r');
```

Plotting both desired and computed responses on the same graph should then give you something similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the very detailed explanation!

works perfectly now :)

Comment: @SimonSymon Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem.